IllegalCharacterError vs ValueError in openpyxl
I need to save Excel files with pandas using openpyxl.
The data is coming from a database and many times the text fields has some strange characters and it raises an IllegalCharacterError. I have a solution for this situation to find out which sheet, which row and which column causes the problem.
But recently the data gave me an error like this:
ValueError: All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no NULL bytes or control characters

How could I turn it into the same error as the other once? Maybe with replacing some bytes?
The example with two texts. The upper one creating ValueError the lower one an IllegalCharacterError.
See the code in gist. stackoverflow can't save the code below properly.
from openpyxl import Workbook

text = "" # Including three bytes: hexadecimal FFBFBF   resulting ValueError
# text = '\x16'                                        # resulting IllegalCharacterError

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.append([text])
wb.save("test.xlsx")

The setup I use is
openpyxl                 3.1.2
OS Linux-6.11.5-200.fc40.x86_64-x86_64-with-glibc2.39 (Fedora)
Python 3.12.7 (main, Oct  1 2024, 00:00:00) [GCC 14.2.1 20240912 (Red Hat 14.2.1-3)]

My original problem with pandas can be also found on the same gist.
My main problem here is, that in pandas the exception is raised in different steps (to_excel vs writer.close) and in the second case I can't even get the text that caused  the problem.
I even thought that I should create an issue with this on openpyxl's github page. I think it should handle the two character encoding problems equally, raising an IllegalCharacterError. Does it make sense?

You may gain some assistance from this Post filtering-out-certain-bytes-in-python

Raising a issue on that Openpyxl github page probably wont help much since that is not where the Devs handle issues. Check the documentation , the correct place is issues. If you think this is an problem that Openpyxl should handle then raise an issue, they can only say 'no'.
